# Query about the mood and tense of 'rule' in 'Britannia rule the waves'

Tags: mood

I am wondering what mood and tense the verb *to rule* is conjugated in the following sentence:

> Britannia rule the waves

I suspect it is the imperative with an explicit subject but I am not sure.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: The whole quote is [Rule, Britannia! rule the waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule,_Britannia!). The exclamation mark points to the imperative. Can you explain why you doubt it is imperative?

Comment: Thanks for your reply fev. I guess I was unsure it was the imperative because of the presence of the subject.

Comment: Britannia is in the vocative. Like in _Run, Forest, run!_.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an incomplete title/line/quote and is wrongly punctuated.

Comment: It can be an imperative with an exhortative spin. *Run, Jane, run!* or *Go, team, go!*

Comment: Though only a fragment was quoted in the question, it illustrates OP's question, and nothing changes grammatically when  *Rule, Brittania!* is included.  Vote to keep it open.

Comment: @fev: I think the whole quote is "Rule, Britannia! Britannia, rule the waves;" as on the second page of sheet music from your link

Comment: Not being a UK subject, I have interpreted it as  a [magical _may_](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf) as in _God Save the King!_, both coming the same exclamatory construction: _May God Save the King!_, and _May Brittania Rule the Waves!_ Magical _may_ is also used in curses, like _May you spend eternity rollerskating on cobblestones!_ or blessings, like _May this house be safe from tigers!_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule,_Britannia!) has a comprehensive article, including a comment on the non-constancy of the lyrics at this point:

> ... Richard Dawkins recounts in his 1976 book 'The Selfish Gene' that the
> repeated exclamation "Rule, Britannia! Britannia, rule the waves!" is
> often rendered as "Rule, Britannia! Britannia rules the waves!",
> changing the meaning of the verse. This addition of a terminal 's' to
> the lyrics is used as an example of a successful meme.

So from a double exclamation to an exclamation plus declarative.

[Wikipedia also gives a comment about the dropping of the comma and exclamation mark from 'Rule, Britannia!', but I don't agree that this implies/forces the change in meaning they claim. I'd say it's merely an attempt to avoid an arguably over-sensational/archaic appearance. Punctuation 'rules' are often relaxed far more than this in lyrics nowadays.]

Comment: I think we agree. Punctuation doesn't *give* meaning to an utterance presented textually. It merely highlights aspects of the utterance, or highlights a potentially viable variant parsing that might or might not have been the intended  original meaning of the speaker or author. It's like the PUSH or PULL engraved on a corridor door; it isn't integral to the functioning of the door, but tells you what to do as you approach the door.

Comment: The oil on the hinges is another apt metaphor: the door doesn't work too smoothly without it.

Comment: "but I don't agree that this implies/forces the change in meaning they claim. ... Punctuation 'rules' are often relaxed far more than this in lyrics nowadays": it's not clear to me when the idea arose that punctuation should be applied to lyrics according to any strict rules, much less in a way that reflects the non-musical context, but the idea clearly arose long after Thomson and Arne.  Furthermore, it is anachronistic to apply modern expectations of punctuation to 18th-century music (and other texts).  Punctuation rules were different then.

Comment: Even lyrics (apart from the most outlandish) attempt to be understandable, and using  punctuation in nonstandard ways is usually counterproductive. But admittedly 'nonstandard' is time-dependent.

Answer (score -1):

Britannia is a Latin name for the nation of the Britons.

Britannia is plural hence rule is 3rd person plural present tense.

rules is a hypercorrection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: According to Wikipedia, 'Pliny referred to the main island as Britannia, with Britanniae describing the island group': the latter looks like the plural form to my eyes. But there is evidence that the original 'rule' in the Arne lyrics was the imperative 'rule!'

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Britannia is portrayed as a woman, so it's feminine not neuter plural.